# Why virtual function's address of virtual table and virtual function's address on class are different?

Tags: c++, virtual-functions

below is my code

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <deque>
#include <Windows.h>

class B {
private:
    int memB;
public:
    B() :memB(0x11111111) {}
    virtual void f1() { puts("B::f1"); }
    virtual void f2() { puts("B::f2"); }
    virtual void f3() { puts("B::f3"); }
    void normal() { puts("non virtual"); }
};

class D :public B {
private:
    int memD;
public:
    D() :memD(0x22222222) {}
    void f1() { puts("D::f1"); }
    void f2() { puts("D::f2"); }
};

int main() {
    B* pB;
    B b;
    D d;

    pB = &b;
    pB->f1();
    pB->f2();
    pB->f3();
    
    pB = &d;
    pB->f1();
    pB->f2();
    pB->f3();

    return 0;
}
```

[image]

and above is my picture of result.

As you can see, addresses of B::f1 and b.__vfptr[0] (which points to B:: f1) are different.

I thought that they would be same, because they point to same function 'B:: f1'.

Why their addresses are different?

I am looking forward your nice answers.

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In x86 (32-bit) Debug mode, MSVC vtable entries point to function trampolines, which contain JMP instructions to the actual virtual functions.

You can easily see it if you open the disassembly window and enter the address from the vtable (e.g. `0xb61276`):

```
B::f1:
00B61276  jmp         B::f1 (0B61970h)
```

It's probably to facilitate setting software breakpoints.

This is not the case in x86 Release or 64-bit mode (probably because in 64-bit mode MSVC debugger always uses hardware breakpoints).